# Grouping phpunit tests. Launching test from specified directory

Tags: phpunit

I have a directory `tests` where I store all my tests.

Hierarchy of `tests` dirrectory

```
tests->
       ApplicationTests->
       IntegrationTests->
                         Factory->
                         Service->
       UnitTests->
```

How can I make phpunit launch tests only from for example `Service` directory, instead of the whole `tests` directory? I read about `@Groups`, but I think that's not what I'm looking for and it would be best if I would not need to edit config files, but some how, do it from the command line.

Comment: If you take a look around on the site you can also find some proposals and Q/A style discussion about this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8313283/367456 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961097/367456 or even some basic explanation on the configuraiton: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19653958/367456

Comment: @hakre Yeah I found similar solutions, to my problem, but I couldn't understand how could I use them. Only after I solved it myself, I understood, how it actually works.

Comment: Yes, hopefully they add to the picture you start to see. What maybe triggered the search for those by me was, that in your answer you're referring to the test-suite (which is very fine btw.) and there is a more zero-conf approach, where you point to the folder of the tests you want to execute `./vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox tests/IntegrationTests/Server` for example. It's compatible with test-suites btw., so you can do the one or the other. So maybe organizing by folder is perhaps the foremost approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quite easy way, even with config editing.

```
phpunit.xml
```

> See: *[The XML Configuration File <sup>Phpunit Docs</sup>](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html)* and *[Organizing Tests <sup>Phpunit Docs<</sup>](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/organizing-tests.html)*

```
<testsuite name="Service">
      <directory>tests/IntegrationTests/Service</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Command line:
`php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox --testsuite Service`